# sh int fa0/0 mac address question

Tags: cisco, mac-address

if i add a device of int fa0/0 will the interface assume the devices mac address? 
i noticed that this interface has a BIA what is it used for?

```
FastEthernet0/0 is administratively down, line protocol is down
  Hardware is Gt96k FE, address is c201.1360.0000 (bia c201.1360.0000)
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. The BIA is the hardware MAC address. You can change the address that is used on the interface.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

A device connected to a switch uses its own interface's MAC address for L2 communication.  The burned in address (BIA) on the switch interface is used in L2 communication originated by or addressed to the switch itself.